# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC 5 Angular 4 app into IIS server?

Tags: asp.net, angular, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new to Angular and started learning Angular. Currently,I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build the Angular app. Basically, my aim is to combine both technologies together where I can use the ASP.NET MVC engine in the back-end and angular features in the front-end.

I have copied the angular-quick tutorial setup from the github and incorporate with my MVC project.It is running locally without any problem.

Now I want to publish this apps from Visual Studio 2017 into local IIS server. It appears that the IIS server does not know how to read the system.config.js files.
I am not able to run the apps from the server.

Do I need to move all the node_modules files into IIS server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When your all the development part is done, you can publish it under Internet Information Server (IIS).

Need to create a production bundle of the Angular 4 application and add hooks into the publishing pipeline that also publishes the production bundles of the Angular 4 application with the rest of the deployment to IIS.

To create production bundles of the Angular application,.csproj project file should be edited and added a production build command to the AfterBuild target.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Exec Command="ng build --prod --deploy-url http://localhost/yourproject/dist/" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' " />

<Exec Command="ng build --deploy-url http://localhost:55499/dist/" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' " />
</Target>
```

Please add below command to the project file which will get executed when publishing the application.

```
<Exec Command="ng build --prod --deploy-url http://localhost/yourproject/dist/" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' "/>
```

Comment: I am using AngularJS, not angular 4. I just compile the apps using Visual Studio 2017 and put the code in the Server. I do not use ng-build type of command at all.